# load content into page asynchronously with ajax promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I want to asynchronously load content into my page when I click on the links on my navigation bar. While, using the .load() method works I am having difficulty figuring out how to make the promise object work the same way. I am also confused as why my form is visible when i click 'home' even though i set it to be hidden.

http://jsfiddle.net/Piq9117/Lzw514md/

```
    // Navigation
        var navigation = (function () {
            var $nav = $('#navigation a');
            var $page = $('#page');
            var $container = $('#container');

        $nav.on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $page.remove();
            dataservice.getPage()
                .done(function (data) {
                $container.html($(data).find('#page'));
                })
                .fail(function (jqXHR, statusText, err) {
                alert(err);
                })
        })
        // the .load works fine..
        // $nav.on('click', function(e) {
        //  e.preventDefault();
        //  var url = $(this).attr('href');
        //  $page.remove();
        //  $container.load(url + ' #page');
        // })


    })();


    // Promise object, passed to navigation
    var dataservice = (function () {

        var getPage = function () {
            var url = $(this).attr('href'); // this returns undefined
            return $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url,
            })
        }

        return {
            getPage: getPage
        }
    })();


    // chache/hide/show form
    (function () {
        var form = {
            init: function () {
                this.cacheDom();
                this.events();
            },
            cacheDom: function () {
                this.$container = $('.container');
                this.$page = this.$container.find('#page');
                this.$showbtn = this.$container.find('#showbtn');
                this.$form = this.$page.find('#form');
                this.$form.hide();
                this.$submitbtn = this.$page.find('#submitbtn');
            },
            events: function () {
                this.$showbtn.on('click', this.showForm.bind(this));
                this.$submitbtn.on('click', this.hideForm.bind(this));
            },
            showForm: function () {
                this.$form.fadeIn(300);
                this.$showbtn.hide(300);
            },
            hideForm: function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(300);
                this.$form.hide(300);
                this.$showbtn.show(300);
            }
        }

        form.init();
    })();
```

Comment: well first off, your form coming back from load does not have the style `display:none` like on the initial load.

Comment: @DataHerder the form is hidden with .hide() method.

Comment: well it's definitely not getting called after you load the data via ajax.

Comment: yeah cuz i have to delegate or bind it. so i switched to just displaying it to none and changing the display with jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` within your `dataservice.getPage()` function is not the dom element that you want it to be. You would need to pass that element in as an argument and since all you really need is the href maybe it would look better just passing in the url

```
var getPage = function (url) {        
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
    })
}
```

Then in even handler pass in the href:

```
  $nav.on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $page.remove();
      dataservice.getPage(this.href) // pass in `href`
        .done(function (data) {
          $container.html($(data).find('#page'));
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, statusText, err) {
          alert(err);
      });
  })
```

Comment: this sort of solved the problem but i had problem parsing the html. it wasnt showing up.

Comment: Things like that are easy to inspect in browser dev tools network where you can dig deep into each request. If answer helped feel free to accept it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a reference to $(this) in your getPage method. $(this) doesn't exist in this context, you have to pass it through all your methods.

```
    // Navigation
var navigation = (function () {
    var $nav = $('#navigation a');
    var $page = $('#page');
    var $container = $('#container')

    $nav.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $page.remove();
        dataservice.getPage($(this))
            .done(function (data) {
            $container.html($(data).find('#page'));
        })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, statusText, err) {
            alert(err);
        })
    })
    // the .load works fine..
    // $nav.on('click', function(e) {
    //  e.preventDefault();
    //  var url = $(this).attr('href');
    //  $page.remove();
    //  $container.load(url + ' #page');
    // })


})();


// Promise object, passed to navigation
var dataservice = (function () {

    var getPage = function ($this) {
        var url = $this.attr('href'); // this returns undefined
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
        })
    }

    return {
        getPage: function($this) {
            getPage($this);
        }
    }
})();


// chache/hide/show form
(function () {
    var form = {
        init: function () {
            this.cacheDom();
            this.events();
        },
        cacheDom: function () {
            this.$container = $('.container');
            this.$page = this.$container.find('#page');
            this.$showbtn = this.$container.find('#showbtn');
            this.$form = this.$page.find('#form');
            this.$form.hide();
            this.$submitbtn = this.$page.find('#submitbtn');
        },
        events: function () {
            this.$showbtn.on('click', this.showForm.bind(this));
            this.$submitbtn.on('click', this.hideForm.bind(this));
        },
        showForm: function () {
            this.$form.fadeIn(300);
            this.$showbtn.hide(300);
        },
        hideForm: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(300);
            this.$form.hide(300);
            this.$showbtn.show(300);
        }
    }

    form.init();
})();
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzw514md/2/) (check your javascript console to see the ajax requests)